# Having a URL like this

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting

I agree, this question will get lots of down votes but I don't care the for system used.

How can I generate a URL like this: `http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/`

If it was my site, I'd do something like: `http://bbc.co.uk/Sport.html` or `http://bbc.co.uk/Sport.php`.

How is the `/sport/0/` generated?

Thanks and I hope you understand the question!

Comment: use .htaccess level url rewritting.

Comment: its going to get downvotes because it shows no research effort. Its not ok to say i'm aware I haven't done any research but still want an answer. This question has been asked many many times in various different ways

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different ways that this *could* be done, but the simplest in this case is:

```
mkdir sport
mkdir sport/0
vim sport/0/index.php
```

Replace `vim` with your editor of choice

Answer (score 0):

That's most likely a route where "sport" is basically the main category you're under, while in this case 0 is the default subcategory of that. Hope it's easy to understand.

If you look at the Headlines they are all under /sport/0/ eg. /sport/0/football/123456. If look at the live stream the is under /sport/live/1233456. I assume here "live" is a subroute of sport.

At the same time, depending how the site is built, "sport" could indicate a module or maybe a controller. We can only guess.

Google can give you more info on routing or url rewrite rules if you're interested in that.

Answer (score -1):

These are called "clean urls".
Here is a [tutorial](http://pixelcode.co.uk/tutorials/webmaster/clean-urls-with-mod_rewrite/) that explains how this is accomplished with PHP.
You need to use the mod_rewrite module and a .htaccess file.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that while your answer remains here, the link and its content might change or be removed.
Please edit your code to include the relevant information from that link.